# Applescript select all checkboxes in scroll area

Tags: applescript

I've automated printing a weekly calendar with 'applescript' and 'Calendar'. There is a scroll area with collection of checkboxes. How do you iterate over every checkbox in a scroll area and uncheck it?

https://gist.github.com/spuder/c92dd0637ce85b6960b81e1415d7c52e

This works but is fragile since the rows are hard coded.

```
-- Click the “<fill in title>” checkbox.
delay 0.5
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click checkbox 1 of row 2 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of window \"Print\" of application process \"Calendar\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

-- Click the “<fill in title>” checkbox.
delay 1
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click checkbox 1 of row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of window \"Print\" of application process \"Calendar\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

-- Click the “<fill in title>” checkbox.
delay 1
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click checkbox 1 of row 4 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of window \"Print\" of application process \"Calendar\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
```

[image]

This seems like it *should* work but it does not uncheck any of the boxes

```
delay 1
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click checkbox 1 of every row of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of window \"Print\" of application process \"Calendar\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave

```
tell application "Calendar"
    activate
    reopen
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Calendar"
    if not (exists of window "Print") then keystroke "p" using command down
    repeat while not (exists of window "Print")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    set everyCheckboxRef to a reference to every checkbox of rows of outline 1 ¬
        of scroll area 1 of window 1
    repeat with i from 1 to count of everyCheckboxRef
        set thisCheckbox to item i of everyCheckboxRef
        if value of thisCheckbox is 1 then perform action "AXPress" of thisCheckbox
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Now it works either way. BTW using `... a reference to every checkbox ...` is faster then my example AppleScript code, so I have to give you a +1 for it.

Comment: As your code is worthy of a +1 also.  I've been doing a lot of research and reading on the "reference to" operator.  Still trying to wrap my head around it and I must admit I still find it confusing more often than not (as I seem To still create more errors rather than solutions with this approach LOL.)  This situation it just seemed to make sense to me

Answer (score 2):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is one way to achieve the goal of unchecking all *checkboxes* in the **Calendars** *section* of the **Print** *dialog* box in the **Calendar** application:

```
    --  # Check to see if Calendar is open and act accordingly.

if running of application "Calendar" then

        --  # Calendar is already open however, make sure the main window is showing not minimized.

    tell application "Calendar"
        if not (visible of window "Calendar") then set visible of window "Calendar" to true
        activate -- # Bring the main window forward.
    end tell

else

        --  # Calendar is not open, so open it.

    tell application "Calendar"
        activate

            --  # Wait for main window before proceeding.

        repeat until exists window "Calendar"
            delay 0.1
        end repeat

    end tell

end if

    --  # Open the Print dialog box.

tell application "System Events" to keystroke "p" using command down

    --  # Make sure the Print dialog box is showing before proceeding.

tell application "Calendar"
    repeat until exists window "Print"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
end tell

    --  # Uncheck all checkboxes in the Calendars scroll area of the Print dialog box.

tell application "System Events"
    tell outline 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Print" of application process "Calendar"
        repeat with i from 1 to (count rows)
            tell row i
                if (count UI element) > 0 then
                    click checkbox 1
                end if
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [`try`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [`error`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html) *statement* in the **[AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10)**. See also [Working with Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, UI Scripting may require the use of the [`delay`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* as appropriate, needed or wanted.